# What does 3/6/9 mean for damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage

For instance, divine sanction says the enemy takes damage equal to 3/6/9 + Charisma modifier. How do I determine how much damage that actually does?

Comment: I was going to suggest a title edit to universalize the question a bit more (because this format is used in lots more places than just damage, with lots more values than 3/6/9), but couldn't come up with anything that didn't look really confusing.

Comment: What uses this notation? I haven't actually seen this used in any book.

Comment: It may not be in books, but it's incredibly common on all forums, and even here, though the added verbosity of answers here often explains it better than elsewhere. But "What does x/y/z mean in 4e" is a far less clear question title, because the key to implicitly understanding what's being referenced is tied to the incremental nature of the tiering. 2/4/6, 2/3/4, 3/6/9, and 1/2/3 cover almost all progression variations.

Comment: This question would be infinitely better if it said where these numbers were seen, as Divine Sanction definitely does *not* say that in the official source.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are the damage per tier.

Many abilities and powers show their damage tiered. 
Being the first number heroic, second number parangon and third epic.

The levels for every tier are,

Heroic:    1-10

Parangon: 11-20

Epic:     21-30